# actions after dismissModalViewControllerAnimated

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiimage

After I select a photo with the camera I'm saving it as `NSData`. This takes a while and I dont want my users to wait for it. I want it to happen at the background. My question is whether it is wise to perform methods after I call "`dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO`".

this is my code, which outputs the following:

debug1
debug2
debug4
debug5
debug6
debug3

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

// Access the uncropped image from info dictionary
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

NSLog(@"debug1");

// Save image in the normal photo album
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);

NSLog(@"debug2");

[[MySingleton sharedSingleton] addImg:image];

NSLog(@"debug3");
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

[_delegate startStep2];

}

-(void) addImg: (UIImage *) img {

NSLog(@"debug4");

NSData *jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([img rotateAndScaleFromCameraWithMaxSize:1500.0], 0.9f);

NSLog(@"debug5");

image   = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:jpegData];

NSLog(@"debug6");
}
```

Can I dismiss the viewcontroller first and than do other stuff, or isnt that a good way?

edit// I did solve the waiting problem by doing this:

```
[[MySingleton sharedSingleton] performSelectorInBackground:@selector(addImg:) withObject:image];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[MySingleton sharedSingleton] performSelectorInBackground:@selector(addImg:) withObject:image];

did the trick..

Answer (score 0):

Once you have `retained` all required info, I think you can dismiss the picker.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to do the stuff first then dismiss the view Controller. U can add the Activity Indicator for user to know the processing is continue..